# Regarding multi domain on same web server

Tags: dns, domain, hosting

I have a question regarding domain hosting and domains sharing of same IP address.

One of my domain is hosted under a shared hosting with dedicated ip. I have mapped the dns record to cloudflare. When I did a reverse ip domain check I realised there are multiple domains hosted under the same IP.

I have did another reverse ip domain check on another domain who has also mapped their dns to cloudflare, and it only shows 1 domain for that ip.

Wondering is this due to the fact that I'm using a shared hosting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly did you perform the "reverse ip domain check"? What tools did you use?

Comment: I'm using this https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted the actual IP address(es) (and hostnames).

Did you also check the forward lookup for the hostnames given by the rDNS?  It is quite possible that the rDNS is polluted with old, possibly invalid, or possibly changed, hostnames.